# Menu doesn't scroll on phones

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Menu doesn't scroll on phones - I need help http://www.ekizceliler.com/

Here have I the section of my style sheet which applies to the menu block on phones:

```
.menu_block {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    left:  0;
    top:   0;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width:  100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

What must i to do for scroll the menu on phones ?

Comment: use overflow property for scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add overflow auto and height to the menu  inside the media query 767px

@media (max-width: 767px)

```
.navmenu {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
overflow-y: auto;
top: 80px;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #fff;
```

}

Comment: Hi Kani Raj, 

Thank You.. work good but only last 3 thinks of the menu doesn't scroll on

I updated new style.css you can watch the website with phone and later with computer/laptop http://www.ekizceliler.com

I hope that you can help me with that too?

Regards.

Comment: hey thats because of nav height just change your css into like following 
"height: 100vh;" into "height: calc(100vh - 110px);"

.navmenu {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
overflow-y: auto;
top: 80px;
height: calc(100vh - 110px) ;
background-color: #fff;
}

Comment: Hi Kani Raj, Thank You again.. Last one thing :D if you watched the website with phone then have you see it too that slide pictures are very huge what can I do for just high so that can everyone see slide pictures without cuting ?

Regards...

Comment: in flexslider.css line no 44 ".flexslider.top_slider {
    min-height: 564px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}"will be there just remove "min-height: 564px;" fully otherwise comment that line because flexslider automatically will set height and your slider will work fine enjoy....

Comment: Hi Kani Raj, I was in holyday. That last 2 things did i today, but there is no change in website flexslider.css and style.css. Maybe did I mistake?

Comment: here is the code's:

flexslider.css: I removed all this: .flexslider.top_slider { min-height: 564px; background-color: #ccc; }

.flexslider {overflow:hidden; position: relative; z-index:2;}
.flexslider.top_slider:before {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 z-index:3;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-image:url(../images/slider/slide_shadow.png);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size:auto 100%;
 -webkit-background-size:auto 100%;

Comment: style.css: I change .navmenu { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; overflow-y: auto; top: 80px; height: calc(100vh - 110px) ; background-color: #fff; }

Here is the code: 

 .navmenu {position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; overflow-y: auto; top: 80px; height: calc(100vh - 110px); background-color: #fff;}
 .navmenu ul {padding:10px 0;}
 .navmenu ul li {display:block; text-align:left;}
 .navmenu ul li a {padding:4px 20px;}